# How can I make the 404 route work in React-Router?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to make a 404 route with react-router and it doesn't work.

I tried `<Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} />` and `<Route component={PageNotFound} />` and wrapped all my routes with `<Switch></Switch`.
My guess is that it doesn't work because I have two `<Switch />` components nested inside each other.

#### App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
              <Route exact path="/profiles" component={Profiles} />
              <Route exact path="/profile/:id" component={Profile} />
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
              </Switch>
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/posts" component={Posts} />
              </Switch>
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/post/:id" component={Post} />
              </Switch>
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/create-profile"
                  component={CreateProfile}
                />
              </Switch>
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/edit-profile"
                  component={EditProfile}
                />
              </Switch>
              <Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} />
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

#### PrivateRoute.js:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

I also tried putting the 404 route just above the first `<PrivateRoute />`. And it works for the non-private routes but I want it to work in all routes.
The example above also messes up the `<PrivateRoute exact path="/posts" component={Posts} />` route.

You can view the website at https://floating-waters-33077.herokuapp.com

Comment: try `<Route component={PageNotFound} />`

Comment: @YahyaAhmed I did. Doens't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is the number of `Switch` blocks you have. You should ideally only have one.
Since each route is `exact` you can condense your `Switch` component children to

```js
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
              <Route exact path="/profiles" component={Profiles} />
              <Route exact path="/profile/:id" component={Profile} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/posts" component={Posts} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/post/:id" component={Post} />
              <PrivateRoute
                exact
                path="/create-profile"
                component={CreateProfile}
              />
              <PrivateRoute
                exact
                path="/edit-profile"
                component={EditProfile}
              />
              <Route component={PageNotFound} />
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

This will allow for the 404 page to be a catch-all if none of the routes match in the overall `Switch` block.